# How to set a datatable to a WPF datagrid C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, binding

I'm new to c# so go easy.

Basically I build a data table ( and I have verified it's not empty) but it doesn't seem to get displayed in my wpf datagrid... I used this example here and applied it:[link text](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/d04229ba-3c96-4aa7-a386-7cd1ce5eedea)

My datagrid remains blank.

Does that example look fine to you guys?

here is my code:

XACML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.TickerSearch"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="TickerSearch" Height="468" Width="907">
<Grid Background="#E6000000" Name="_grid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="244*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="37*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,15,0,0" Name="txtSearchTker" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="225" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <Button Content="Search" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,160,0,0" Name="btnSearch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" Click="btnSearch_Click" />
    <ListBox Height="114" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,224,0,0" Name="lstResults" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="225" Visibility="Hidden" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="#FFFFB000" />
    <Button Content="Select" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,366,0,0" Name="btnSelect" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <Label Content="Start Date: " Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,65,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71" Background="#00FFB000" FontFamily="Georgia" Foreground="#FFFFB000" />
    <Label Content="End Date:" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,93,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71" Background="#00FFB000" FontFamily="Georgia" Foreground="#FFFFB000" />
    <DatePicker Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="93,65,0,0" Name="dateFrom" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" />
    <DatePicker Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="93,94,0,0" Name="toDate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" />
    <Label Content="Just Today" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,122,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71" Background="#00FFB000" FontFamily="Georgia" Foreground="#FFFFB000" />
    <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="93,127,0,0" Name="chkBoxToday" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15" />
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="315" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="285,68,0,0" x:Name="_dataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="468" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}" Background="#C6F7F700"></DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

c#:

```
            _ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable table = yahooFinance.lookupSymbol();
            _ds.Tables.Add(table);
            _grid.DataContext = _ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Show some code so we can help...

Comment: added into original post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change it to `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`.

Also, set `AutoGenerateColumns` to true.  (Or explicitly specify columns)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, I'd suggest the two most important points are:

- setting the DataContext with `myGrid.DataContext = myDS.Tables[0];`
- having your XAML DataGrid include the ItemsSource property:

  `<dg:DataGrid    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}"`